# Plot3D in a loop for Riemann surfaces of the nth-root

Tags: plotting, complex

I would like to plot the Riemann surfaces for $n$ functions of the form:

> $$
> >     f(z) = z^{\frac{1}{n}} = (x + iy)^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

For example for the function

> $$
> >     f(z) = z^{\frac{1}{2}}  $$

I want it to be:

```
p2 = Plot3D[{Im[E^[I Pi] (x + I*y)^(1/2)],  Im[E^[2 I Pi] (x + I*y)^(1/2)]},
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> {40, 120},
    Mesh -> 25,
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
    ImageSize -> size
  ]
```

[image]
 For the function

> $$    f(z) = z^{\frac{1}{3}}  $$

```
p3 = Plot3D[{Im[(x + I y)^(1/3)], Im[E^(2 I Pi/3) (x + I y)^(1/3)], 
   Im[E^(4 I Pi/3) (x + I y)^(1/3)]},
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> {40, 120},
    Mesh -> 25,
    BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
  ]
```

[image]

And so on...

Now, since with growing $n$ the number of imaginary part of the functions grow, so I nested a `For` loop with a `While` loop

```
For[n = 2, n < 4, n++,
 f[x_, y_] = (x + I y);
 i = 1;
    Plot3D[
    {
    While[i < n + 1,
        Im[E^(i I Pi /n) f[x, y]^(1/n)]; i++
        ]
    },
    {x, -2, 2},
    {y, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> {40, 120},
    Mesh -> 25,
    BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
    ]
 ]
```

But this does not produce any output, and I think the bug is in:

```
       {
        While[i < n + 1,
            Im[E^(i I Pi /n) f[x, y]^(1/n)]; i++
            ]
        }
```

as it does not produce a list of

```
   {Im[E^( I Pi/4) f[x, y]^(1/n)], Im[E^( I Pi/2) f[x, y]^(1/n)], ...}
```

also, I don't know how to put the comma between the functions `Im[E^(i I Pi /n) f[x, y]^(1/n)]`...

how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define

```
riemann[n_] :=
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate@Table[Im[E^(i I Pi/n) (x + I y)^(1/n)], {i, 1, n + 1}],
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> {10, 20},
  Mesh -> 5,
  BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]]

riemann[3]
```

[image]

Or

```
riemann /@ Range[4]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to the `Table` command. This produces a list of the desired plots.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x + I y);
n = 3;
plotlist = Table[
  Plot3D[
   Im[E^(i I Pi/n) f[x, y]^(1/n)],
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   PlotPoints -> {40, 120},
   Mesh -> 25,
   BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
   ],
  {i, 1, n + 1}]
```

If you like to have all of them in one single plot, you can use `Show` like this:

```
Show[plotlist, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I have a problem with the `ColorFunction` as the `Hue[z]` is different for all the $n$ plots..

Comment: You can also use the `Table` within  `Plot3D` similar to your first try with the `While` construct. This should fix it.